# QML: Bind loop detected without double assignment

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

As far as I know the bind loop happens when I try to assign two properties each other. Example:

```
CheckBox {
    checked: Settings.someSetting                         
    onCheckedChanged: {
        Settings.someSetting = checked;
    }
}
```

but in my scenario I can't see such a "double assignment". I report here the *full* code:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

Window {
    visible: true;
    width: 500
    height: 500

    Rectangle {
        id: main
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "black"

        property bool spinning: true
        property bool stopping: false

        Rectangle {
            x: 0.5 * parent.width
            y: 0.5 * parent.height
            width: 10
            height: 200
            radius: 5
            color: 'red'

            transformOrigin: Item.Top
            rotation: {
                if (main.stopping)
                {
                    main.spinning = false;
                    main.stopping = false;
                }

                return timer.angle
            }
        }

        Timer {
            id: timer
            interval: 5
            repeat: true
            running: true
            onTriggered: {
                if (main.spinning) angle += 1;
            }
            property real angle
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: control
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                main.stopping = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you click with the mouse you will get the warning:

> qrc:/main.qml:17:9: QML Rectangle: Binding loop detected for property "rotation"

I don't see my mistake. I'm using flags (bool variables) to control the execution of my code. I know in this case I can just stopping the timer directly, but the actual program is more complex than this example.

Comment: I think your design is wrong: Why do you use the 2 flags: spinning ans stopping?

Comment: As said, this is just the famous *minimal and compilable* example to show the problem I'm facing. I'm aware in this simple case both flags are not needed. But they help me to trigger the binding loop I'm not seeing...

Comment: The binding is in the following lines: `if (main.stopping)
                {
                    main.spinning = false;
                    main.stopping = false;
                }`,  the change of rotation is triggered by the change of main.stopping: let's say that change main.stopping is given by the mouseArea, then it will be called a rotation, but inside this there is an if, and in this you are changing back to main.stopping , where he will call rotation back.

Comment: Why is triggered by the change of `main.stopping`? Its state doesn't affect the returned value, `timer.angle`.

Comment: if it affects it, if a property in QML changes all the elements that depend on it will change.

Comment: Got it. That wasn't clear to me. Thanks. You could make your comments as an answer.

Comment: already publish my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding is in the following lines:

```
rotation: {
    if (main.stopping)
    {
        main.spinning = false;
        main.stopping = false;
    }

    return timer.angle
}
```

The change of rotation is triggered by the change of main.stopping: let's say that change main.stopping is given by the mouseArea, then it will be called a rotation, but inside this there is an if, and in this you are changing back to main.stopping , where he will call rotation back.

**If a property in QML changes all the elements that depend on it will change**